# Javascript issue with selector session storage

Tags: javascript, session-storage

Hello so I added some javascript to keep selection stored when page is reloaded in my select menu , but the issue is when I load the page for the first time nothing appears in my select menu (First choice of the select menu)
[what appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Ood.png)

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var selItem = sessionStorage.getItem("SelItem");  
    $('#date').val(selItem);
    }
    $('#date').change(function() { 
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        sessionStorage.setItem("SelItem", selVal);
    });
```

```html
 <label  class="op" for="date">Periode : </label>
<select id="date">
  <option value="toutes">Toutes</option>
  <option value="2019">Année en cours</option>
  <option value="2018">Année pécédente</option>
 <option value="2017">Année -2</option>
 <option value="2016">Année -3</option>
 <option value="2015">Année -4</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="date1" class="datepicker w100" value="2015-01-01"type="date" placeholder="Du  jj/mm/aaaa">&nbsp;<input type ="hidden"name="date2" id="date2" value="2026-12-31"class="datepicker w100" type="date" placeholder="Au jj/mm/aaaa">
<br/>
```

Comment: So do not set the value if nothing exists?

Answer (score 1):

So only set the value if there is something in storage.

```
if (selItem) $('#date').val(selItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was a bit dumb .